# Chrome alert Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm working by selenium to test my python module. I have a problem with Chrome, when in my test an alert is opened. My code:

```
self.context.dojo.query( '#mybutton' ).click()                                                            
self.context.driver.switch_to_alert().accept()
```

when I launch my test on chrome, after click(), I have an error:
WebDriverException: Message: u'Script execution failed. Script: \n                query( "#mybutton" )[0].click();\n            ;\n An open modal dialog blocked the operation'
and test failed. 
This test on Firefox is OK. 
Thanks

Comment: I can't test this due to 64bit Chrome, but could it be that something is popping up before `mybutton` can be clicked? You say it's happening after click though, so maybe not. Having the rest of the code could be helpful.

Comment: maybe in Firefox the alert is not modal?

Comment: TankorSmash, I'm sure that error is on click!!

Comment: I have a similar issue currently, my dodgy method of dealing with this is to (horribly) wait a second and then send an ENTER keypress or a TAB+ENTER keypress. In .NET I know there is a default alert action in the new Selenium, but I do not believe the Python bindings have this.